# matplotlib: add the record counts for each category of a box plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, boxplot

I am using the following code to create a box plot:

```
df.assign(index=df.groupby('stage').cumcount()).pivot('index','stage','days').plot(kind='box', sym='bD', showmeans = True)
```

[image]
The code works fine, but I am wondering would it be possible to add the record number for each category (box)? Thanks!

Comment: matplotlib's boxplot function takes a `labels` parameter. You need to compute your labels and pass them. Alternatively, compute the labels you want directly in your dataframe and use that as the grouping column"

Comment: Look for this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45476485/7390366

Comment: @pcu, I want to avoid using seaborn. Any way to do it directly?

Comment: @PaulH, I already have xticks, so I don't want the xticks-label. Can we have the record count just on the box, not as xtick-label? Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame my example does not use the seaborn calls to add labels.

Comment: @Edamame use `ax.text` or `ax.annonate`