# Python Seaborn Boxplot: Overlay 95 percentile values on whisker

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I want to overlay 95 percentile values on seaborn boxplot. I could not figure out the ways to overlay text or if there is seaborn capability for that. How would I modify following code to overlay the 95 percentile values on plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(200, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))*100
alphabet = list('AB')
df['Gr'] = np.random.choice(np.array(alphabet, dtype="|S1"), df.shape[0])
df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Gr'], value_vars = ['A','B','C','D'])
sns.boxplot(x = "variable", y="value", hue = 'Gr',  data=df_long, whis = [5,95])
```

Comment: This post should help you to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649501/labeling-boxplot-in-seaborn-with-median-value. Just replace the median computation to compute the 95 percentile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider seaborn's `plot.text`, borrowing from [@bernie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649501/labeling-boxplot-in-seaborn-with-median-value) (also a healty +1 for including sample dataset). The only challenge is adjusting the alignment due to grouping in *hue* field to have labels overlay over each boxplot series. Even have labels color coded according to series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(61518)
# ... same as OP

# 95TH PERCENTILE SERIES
pctl95 = df_long.groupby(['variable', 'Gr'])['value'].quantile(0.95)
pctl95_labels = [str(np.round(s, 2)) for s in pctl95]

# GROUP INDEX TUPLES
grps = [(i, 2*i, 2*i+1) for i in range(4)]
# [(0,0,1), (1,2,3), (2,4,5), (3,6,7)]

pos = range(len(pctl95))

# ADJUST HORIZONTAL ALIGNMENT WITH MORE SERIES
for tick, label in zip(grps, hplot.get_xticklabels()):
    hplot.text(tick[0]-0.1, pctl95[tick[1]] + 0.95, pctl95_labels[tick[1]], 
               ha='center', size='x-small', color='b', weight='semibold')

    hplot.text(tick[0]+0.1, pctl95[tick[2]] + 0.95, pctl95_labels[tick[2]], 
               ha='center', size='x-small', color='g', weight='semibold')
sns.plt.show()
```

[image: Plot Output]