# How can I get statistics values from a boxplot when using seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I made a boxplot by seaborn, and I'd like to get some statistic values such as minimum, first quartile, median, third quartile, maximum also outliers.

Is there any functions or attributes to directly gather these values via seaborn boxplot.

Or I should calculate these by other packages or manually.

Comment: You better calculate them, because seaborn has no interface to retrieve the values. The only other option would be to querry each coordinate of the rectangles and lines from the plot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use pandas' `describe()` function, eventually coupled with `groupby()`. For example:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
x_val = "day"
y_val = "total_bill"
hue_val = "time"
ax = sns.boxplot(x=x_val, y=y_val, hue=hue_val, data=tips)
```

[image]

```
tips.groupby([x_val,hue_val])[y_val].describe()
```

output:

```
             count       mean       std    min      25%     50%      75%  \
day  time                                                                  
Thur Lunch    61.0  17.664754  7.950334   7.51  12.4300  16.000  20.2700   
     Dinner    1.0  18.780000       NaN  18.78  18.7800  18.780  18.7800   
Fri  Lunch     7.0  12.845714  2.842228   8.58  11.1250  13.420  14.7000   
     Dinner   12.0  19.663333  9.471753   5.75  12.3525  18.665  23.8825   
Sat  Dinner   87.0  20.441379  9.480419   3.07  13.9050  18.240  24.7400   
Sun  Dinner   76.0  21.410000  8.832122   7.25  14.9875  19.630  25.5975   

               max  
day  time           
Thur Lunch   43.11  
     Dinner  18.78  
Fri  Lunch   16.27  
     Dinner  40.17  
Sat  Dinner  50.81  
Sun  Dinner  48.17
```